# How do I move snake as intended in a snakeGame?

Tags: c++, sfml

I actually posted one similar question but without any non working code. Now i've got some. So i want to make snake move in one direction(ex: UP) until i press the other button(DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT) where i would change direction to that.

However, i've got this piece of code where i commented out one of the problems, but now it only works partially in this manner:

**If i press UP i can only press DOWN once more and than it keeps moving forever, if i press LEFT or RIGHT i can only press UP or DOWN and then alternate so DOWN or UP and it keeps moving in that direction forever**

Here is the code:

```
void Game::ProcessEvents(){
    sf::Event event;
    while (myWindow.pollEvent(event)){
            switch(event.type){
                    case sf::Event::KeyPressed : handlePlayerInput(event.key.code, true); break;
                    //case sf::Event::KeyReleased : handlePlayerInput(event.key.code, false); break;
                    case sf::Event::Closed : myWindow.close(); break;
            }
    }
}

void Game::handlePlayerInput(sf::Keyboard::Key key, bool isPressed){
    if (key == sf::Keyboard::W || key == sf::Keyboard::Up) movingUp = isPressed;
    else if (key == sf::Keyboard::S || key == sf::Keyboard::Down) movingDown = isPressed;
    else if (key == sf::Keyboard::A || key == sf::Keyboard::Left) movingLeft = isPressed;
    else if (key == sf::Keyboard::D || key == sf::Keyboard::Right) movingRight = isPressed;
}

void Game::update(){
    sf::Vector2f movement(0.0f, 0.0f);
    if (movingUp)    {   movingLeft = false; movingRight = false; movingDown = false; movement.y -= 0.1f;}
    if (movingDown)  {   movingUp = false; movingLeft = false; movingRight = false;  movement.y += 0.1f;  }
    if (movingLeft)  {   movingRight = false; movingUp = false; movingDown = false;  movement.x -= 0.1f;  }
    if (movingRight) {   movingLeft = false; movingDown = false; movingUp = false;  movement.x += 0.1f;   }

    isColliding(movement);
}
```

Comment: The only question I found here is: _"How do I move snake as intended in a snakeGame?"_ You redraw the snake at the new position.

Comment: I'm sorry but that is too vague. I at least gave some code so i assume someone understood what i meant by this.

Comment: To save time, concentrate on moving the head and the tail.  The rest of the body doesn't really move.

Comment: Doesn't really move? Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it:

1. Instead of having multiple bools have a single variable that denotes the direction. It can be an enum.

```cpp
enum class Dir { up, down, left, right };

void Game::handlePlayerInput(sf::Keyboard::Key key, bool isPressed){
    if (key == sf::Keyboard::W || key == sf::Keyboard::Up) direction = Dir::up;
    else if (key == sf::Keyboard::S || key == sf::Keyboard::Down) direction = Dir::down;
    else if (key == sf::Keyboard::A || key == sf::Keyboard::Left) direction = Dir::left;
    else if (key == sf::Keyboard::D || key == sf::Keyboard::Right) direction = Dir::right;
```

2. Then use that variable to compute the movement

```cpp
void Game::update(){
    sf::Vector2f movement(0.0f, 0.0f);

    if (direction == Dir::up) movement.y -= 0.1f;
    else if (direction == Dir::down) movement += 0.1f;
    else if (direction == Dir::left) movement.x -= 0.1f;
    else if (direction == Dir::right) movement += 0.1f;

    isColliding(movement);
```

Answer (score 2):

Oof I'm not the biggest fan of how you're reading inputs and then transforming that to your `movement` object. For example, if `movingUp` is true, when will it ever be set to false? The answer is NEVER! There is no way for that to happen!

Instead, I'd make an enum with a single variable for the current direction of movement:

```
enum Dir { RIGHT, LEFT, UP, DOWN };
Dir curr_dir = RIGHT; // Start the game moving right
```

Now your `handlePlayerInput` logic can look like:

```
if (key == sf::Keyboard::W || key == sf::Keyboard::Up) curr_dir = UP;
else if (key == sf::Keyboard::S || key == sf::Keyboard::Down) curr_dir = DOWN;
else if (key == sf::Keyboard::A || key == sf::Keyboard::Left) curr_dir = LEFT;
else if (key == sf::Keyboard::D || key == sf::Keyboard::Right) curr_dir = RIGHT;
```

And the `update` logic can now be:

```
switch(curr_dir) {
    case UP:
        movement.y -= 0.1f;
        break;
    case DOWN:
        movement.y += 0.1f;
        break;
    case RIGHT:
        movement.x -= 0.1f;
        break;
    case LEFT:
        movement.x += 0.1f;
        break;
}
```